# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function

Tags: visualforce, jquery

```
if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'tabDiv'  && $(e.target).parents('div#tabDiv').length == 0 && serviceContainer.has(e.target).length === 0){
                $('#tabDiv').parent().parent().find("input[id$='_serviceName']").css('display', '')
                $('#tabDiv').parent().remove();
            }
```

I am getting the **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function** error. and visualforce page is not working properly. we have changed the Jquery library version from 2.2.4 to 3.4.1 currently. is this change causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when changing from version 2 to 3, jquery has implemented `closure` and `strict` in library.

Try putting below line in first line of script:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 1):

it worked. the error was in `j$(window).load(function() {});`. changed the code to

`j$(window).on("load", function() {});`

according to the new jquery version library.

also added `jQuery.noConflict();` method and it worked fine.